# Is there a particularly elegant way to do a count query with Rails 3 / Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

Here's a Rails2 query:

```
Foo.find_by_bar_and_baz('a-bar', 'a-baz', :select =>'count(*) as the_count' ).the_count.to_i
```

The query is ugly, but the resulting SQL is ideal.

Is there a more elegant way to do this in Rails 3 / Arel?

**edit**

this is prettier but still no Arel magic:

```
Foo.count( :conditions => "bar = 'a-bar' and baz = 'a-baz'" )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Foo.where(['bar = ? and baz = ?', 'a-bar', 'a-baz']).count
```

Comment: yay! or even cuter: `Foo.where( :bar => 'a-bar', :baz => 'a-baz' ).count`

Comment: or without the array: `Foo.where('bar = ? and baz = ?', 'a-bar', 'a-baz').count`

Comment: A Rails 3, real-world example: `Job.where(is_active: 1, is_approved: 1).count`